# The use of phrase "years ago" in context

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it natural to say *years ago* meaning a lot of years ago? For example:

> I was an excellent football player years ago.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word years is the key here, since it's plural.

> **Ago** - You use ago when you are referring to past time. For example, if something happened one year ago, it is one year since it happened. If it happened a long time ago, it is a long time since it happened. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ago)

Since we have specified that it is year**s**, this means it's more than one. Not specifying how many years. i.e. saying:

> *two* years ago
>
> *a few* years ago
>
> *several* years ago

Then we can assume that it is so many years ago that we have forgotten the exact time period. Hence, "years ago" tends to imply a long time.

Comment: People will often use ***many*** *years*, but certainly not always. And, barring further clarification, I'd say that *many* is assumed to be present, even if it isn't. More generally, if you *don't* mean many, you'll clarify. As in this answer.